# What is the purpose of the 8 tooth timing gear?

Tags: piece-information, technic, gears

I recently ran across the [32060 Technic Gear Timing Wheel 8 Tooth](https://rebrickable.com/parts/32060/technic-gear-timing-wheel-8-tooth/) element when sorting a mixed bag of parts.

[image: Element render]

This element doesn't appear in many sets as a functional element. Here's one example from the [Barcode-Multi-Set (8479)](https://brickset.com/sets/8479-1/Barcode-Multi-Set) set:

[image: Instruction step]

What is the purpose of this element, and how does it work? I'm guessing from the name that it has something to do with timing. Perhaps it is used as a rotary encoder somehow?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When looking at [Blakbird's Technicopedia](http://www.technicopedia.com/8479.html) page for this Technic set, this part is indeed used as a rotary encoder in combination with the bar code scanner.

See the last entry on the page.

[image: Photo showing timing gear in position to be read properly]

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks! I didn't realize that the barcode scanner in that set could be used to read speed that way.